# Handling notification click events in iOS PWAs using service workers

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently working on a Progressive Web App (PWA) with push notification functionality, and I'm facing an issue specifically on iOS. I have implemented a service worker that listens for the 'notificationclick' event, which is fired when a user clicks on a notification. However, on iOS PWAs, this event doesn't seem to be triggered, and I'm unable to handle the notification click.
Also onMessage event from firebase/messaging isn't logging anything, while app is activated. this problem exists only on iOS. here is the code snippets i wrote

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => { // firebase-messaging-sw.js
  debugger;
  console.log(event, 'event');
  const notification = event?.notification?.data?.['FCM_MSG'];
  event.notification.close();

  event.waitUntil(
    clients
      .matchAll({
        type: 'window',
      })
      .then(() => {
        return clients.openWindow(onNotificationAction(notification['data']));
      }),
  );
});

onMessage(messaging, (payload) => { // app.component.ts
   console.log('Message received. ', payload);
});
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Tried to listen all the events on serviceWorker, looks like it only fires install and activated events when notifications are registered.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Also only on iOS! Do you found a solution by now? Maybe it's an iOS/PWA Bug? Also found this on the apple dev forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/726793

Comment: Yes you should run it on HTTPS environment

Comment: I already use https but the notificationclick doesn’t trigger on iOS pwa. Could you maybe provide the onNotificationAction and the notification data you send? On which attribute do you put the link to open?

Comment: i have modified my answer, please check it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works, just the webpage should be hosted on an HTTPS environment.

this is payload i send
`{ "to": "tokenId", "notification": { "title": "Background Message Title", "body": "Background message body" }, "data": { "badge": 20, "notificationType": "Test.Type", "silent": false, "title": "Background Message Title", "body": "Background message body" } }`

I send all the necessary info to data and i generate link based on that data in notificationClick method, here is the code snippet

```js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', async (event) => {
  const notification = event?.notification?.data?.FCM_MSG;

  event.notification.close();

  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({ type: 'window', includeUncontrolled: true, userVisibleOnly: true }).then(function (clientList) {
      // Check if the PWA is already open and focus on it
      for (let i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
        let client = clientList[i];
        if ('url' in client && client.url.includes('generate or get URL from data')) && 'focus' in client)
          return client.focus();
      }

      // Open a new window with the provided URL
      if (clients.openWindow) {
        clients.openWindow('generate or get URL from data');
      }
    }),
  );
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).